# C# JsonArray comparison ignoring the order of the properties

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I am using JsonDiffPatch and C# to compare the following two json.I am not able to figure out how to ignore the ordering inside the array while comparison.the two json are as follows:The transmission type inside the transmission address are in different order in the two json(first had email and telephone and the second has telephone and email.

```
first Json File
 "TestContacts": [
    {
      "$values": [
        {
          "Contact": {
            "Addresses": {
              "$values": [
                {
                  "Contact": {},
                  "TransmissionAddresses": {
                    "$values": [
                      {
                        "FirstLine": "test.test1@test.com.au",
                        "TransmissionType": "EMAIL",
                        "AI": {
                          "CNM": "SYSTEM",                              
                        },
                        "V": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "FirstLine": "+11 0 1234 5678",
                        "TransmissionType": "TELEPHONE",
                        "AI": {
                          "CNM": "SYSTEM",


                        },
                        "V": 0
                      }
                    ]
                  },
```

Second json File

```
{
          "Contact": {
            "Addresses": {
              "$values": [
                {
                  "Contact": {},
                  "TransmissionAddresses": {
                    "$values": [
                      {
                        "FirstLine": "+11 0 1234 5678",
                        "TransmissionType": "TELEPHONE",
                        "AI": {
                          "CNM": "SYSTEM",                            

                        },
                        "V": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "FirstLine": "test.test1@test.com.au",
                        "TransmissionType": "EMAIL",
                        "AI": {
                          "CNM": "SYSTEM",                             
                        },
                        "V": 0
                      }
                    ]
                  },
```